# Checkbox: how to display text?

Tags: html, css

I want to display the related text of the checkbox along with it.

```
<input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Admin"><span>Admin User</span>
```

This is the most used markup to do that. But it doesn't feel good to use a separate `span` for the check box. And it doesn't even look good in a form.

Is there a way to relate these two with each other? Or what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

use a `Label` and the [for](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp) attribute.

> The for attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to

```
<input id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Admin" />
<label for="Checkbox1">AdminUser</label>
```

Also give your input a `name`

Comment: Input tag should be self-closed. Isn't it?

Comment: The slash at the end of self-closing elements are entirely optional in HTML5.

Answer (score 28):

Instead of using `for` attribute you can use the nested `<input type="checkbox">`:

```
<label><input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox">Admin User</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `<span>` you can use the [`<label>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)-tag:

```
<label for="Checkbox1">Admin User</label>
```

It will 'attach' the label to your checkbox in a sense that when the label is clicked, it is as if the user clicked the checkbox.

For the styling, you need to apply your own styles to make them look 'together' yourself.